# select rows by element components of timestamp

Tags: r, select, vector, timestamp

I have a vector made up of timestamps as `POSIXlt`, format: "2015-01-05 15:00:00, which I extracted from a timeframe.

I want to reassign the vector by loosing all elements where `Minutes != 00`

I've tried

```
vector <- vector[format(vector, "%M") == 00,]
```

which creates the following error of missing argument

> Error in lapply(X = x, FUN = "[", ..., drop = drop) : 
>     argument is missing, with no default

Also tried

```
vector <- vector["%M""== 00]
```

Which is seems to be an open command

Since POSIX time is stored as number of elapsed seconds since 1 Jan 1970, I guess that I could do this by excluding from my vector all elements which are not multiple of 3600. I rather not use this approach though. Thank you in advance, I'm new to `R`.

Comment: Your command without the comma should work `v2[format(v2, '%M')=='00']` as `v2` is a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format returns a character type, not numeric, so you should compare it to "00". Also the comma is not needed, as there's only 1 dimension.

```
vector <- vector[format(vector, "%M") == "00"]
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun and Balint. Very hepful. @balint, you mean that this way my final vector doesn't have POSIX dates right? but rather character strings. Is there a way to prevent loosing this rather then re-coercing as suggested above by @akrun?

Comment: OK. Got it. using v2[v2$min==0] as suggested by @akrun does the selection while keeping data type as POSIX. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
v2[!v2$min]
#[1] "2015-01-05 15:00:00 EST" "2015-01-05 15:00:30 EST"
```

Or your command should also work without the `comma`

#### data

```
v1 <- c("2015-01-05 15:00:00", "2015-01-05 15:45:00", "2015-01-05 15:00:30")
v2 <- strptime(v1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
vector2 <- vector2[v2$min==0]
```

I reassign vector 2 (v2) excluding all elements where minutes are not 0.
This was suggested by @akrun.
It does the selection while keeping data type as POSIX.

There were two issues with the first option of initial code:

1.function format() returns character;

2.there was a "," before last "]", which meant that the function was expecting another argument, which does not make sense to a vector as explained by @balint.

With the second option initially submitted there were a few syntax mistakes. The correct syntax is that on this answer, as suggested by @akron.